# Nginx not passing uri to php5-fpm, instead serving as text file

Tags: nginx, php5, php-fpm, fastcgi

as stated above the uri isn't being passed to nginx. I've included the entire "try" block to show this.

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    set $page_to_view "/index.php";
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
}
```

So it's essentially saying "oh hey we did $uri.php and that file exists, let's server it instead of actually sending it to php."

and my fpm portion is below.

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
#   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

#   # With php5-cgi alone:
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Pretty much stock. So what I don't get is why in the world nginx isn't doing it anymore. I know it was working with fastcgi under debian but now it isn't, and I lost my old config file due to a HDD crash and it's the one file I didn't backup before sending the drive back as I thought it'd be perfectly AOK to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what URI you're trying to load but I'm going to assume it doesn't end in `.php`.

Your issue here is that you're not taking the `try_files` directive literally as the name implies. It is specifically try a **file.** It's documented as `try_files file ... uri;` meaning that only the last argument is going to be treated as a fall back causing an internal rewrite. Any argument before the last one is tested as a static file and if found is served as a static file.

This means you can do `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;` but you cannot do `try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/`

Comment: I guess I was wrong, I thought that it'd do the rewrite as soon as it encountered the whole $uri.php. I guess I was wrong thanks for the help. Marking this one as correct then.

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

with

```
location ~ \.php {
```

and $document_root with actual dir where php file is placed

for ex.

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: why downvote ?  I have working setup which is working with this configuration.